# ReferenceError: global is not defined when using amazon-cognito-identity-js with Quasar

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-cognito, quasar-framework

I'm trying to implement user authentication using AWS Cognito in a web app built using Quasar. My code uses the Vue Composition API:

```
import { CognitoUserPool } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js'
  
  export default defineComponent({
    name: 'AdminMainPage',
    components: { },
    setup () {
      function getCurrentUser() {
        const userPool = new CognitoUserPool({
          UserPoolId: "<USER-POOL-ID>",
          ClientId: "<CLIENT-ID>",
        });
        return userPool.getCurrentUser();
      }
      
      console.log(getCurrentUser());
      return {
        
      };
    }
  });
```

However, upon loading the page, I get an error:

```
client-entry.js:61 ReferenceError: global is not defined at node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/node_modules/buffer/index.js
```

I read in other answers that this might be solved by defining `global` as empty in `vite.config.js`, and so removed the comment block around `extendViteConf` in `quasar.config.js` and defined `global` as empty:

```
extendViteConf (viteConf, { isServer, isClient }) {
  define: {
    global: {}
  }
},
```

However, the error still appears.

Any help would be appreciated, I am currently at the end of my wits and on the verge of switching back to Firebase for the simple reason that it actually works.